# Array shuffling not working

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, random, shuffle

I am trying to write code to shuffle an Array without using Collections.

My shuffle code

the Amounts

```
private double amounts[] = { 0, 0.01, 1000000, 25, 250000, 75, 50, 1000,
            200, 100, 400000, 750, 5000, 750000, 500, 100000, 300, 75000, 800,
            20, 300000, 10, 50, 750, 25, 5, 1 };

public void Shuffle(){

        Random rgen = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i > amounts.length; i++) {
            int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(amounts.length);
            double temp = amounts[i];
            amounts[i] = amounts[randomPosition];
            amounts[randomPosition] = temp;
    }
    }
```

the code that initiates it

```
public void casesSetup() {  

        for (int i = 0; i < briefcase.length; i++) {

            if (i == 0) {

            } else {
                briefcase[i] = new Briefcase();
                double value = amounts[i];
                briefcase[i].setAmount(value);
                briefcase[i].setFace(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

my problem here is that they are not being randomized anyone has an idea why?

Comment: try doing `i < amounts.length` instead of `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tip is to start shuffling in reverse:

```
Random rgen = new Random();
for (int i = amounts.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
   int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(i + 1);
   double temp = amounts[i];
   amounts[i] = amounts[randomPosition];
   amounts[randomPosition] = temp;
}
```

Assuming that the distribution of Random.nextInt(N) is uniform on 0..N-1 this will shuffle your array with each permutation being equally as likely. The argumentation for that is straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

for loop in your first snippet seem to be wrong

```
   for (int i=0; i > amounts.length; i++) {
```

shouldn't it be

```
   for (int i=0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Store the values in a List and use 
Collections.shuffle http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

Hand rolling this on your own seems unnecesary

Comment: Yep, obviously. Unless he's doing it as a paractice/homework or simply to learn Java?

Comment: Also, shuffling is actually a rather hard problem which is *very* easy to get wrong. Yes, use `Collection.shuffle` and be done with it.

Comment: @Andrew: You may want to mention that in your question.

Comment: @Andrew: Random is part of the API as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your for loop being wrong, you should change

```
rgen.nextInt(amounts.length)
```

to

```
rgen.nextInt(amounts.length - i) + i
```

to get a uniform random distribution.